# Why aren't wide screen monitors wide enough to play wide screen movies?

Tags: widescreen

Why do wide screen movies not play in full screen on my wide screen monitor?

Is this some sort of conspiracy?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer. What is your operating system? Grahphics card? Monitor make and model? What program are you using to watch movies?

Comment: @DavidPostill You don't need other incitement. Wide screen movies are mostly 2,35:1 and wide screen monitors are mostly 16:9. So it's do not depend on operating system, graphic card, organ and whatever else.

Comment: Movies are a projected image, and the aspect ratio can be almost anything that the movie's creator wants it to be (using masking).  A computer monitor is a manufactured,  direct-view device, and has to have a reasonable aspect ratio to perform actual computer-type work.  Even TVs, a video device, have never been capable of being as wide as movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because movies is not primary reason most people buy a monitor.

Also, "wide screen" is not set dimension and there is no standard for film makers what aspect ratio they should use. Most movies however have 16:9 aspect ratio, and they fit perfectly on 16:9